# SAS Export date format

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to import data (successfully) from a folder that is a date so the file path reads /year/month/date (*today's date)

I am then tweaking some of the data (again successfully). Once that is done I want to export it to a folder that is 29 days forward from the folder I took it from.

Here is my current macro:

```
%LET TODAY = %SYSFUNC(TODAY());
%PUT &TODAY;
%LET TODAYA = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(&TODAY,DDMMYYn8.));
%PUT &TODAYA;
%LET TWENTYNINE = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(&TODAY.+29,DDMMYYn8.)); 
%PUT &TWENTYNINE;
%LET T_DATE = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(&TODAY,DDMMYYn8..));
%LET T_YEAR = %SYSFUNC(YEAR(&TODAY));
%LET T_MONTH = %SYSFUNC(MONTH(&TODAY));
%LET P_DATE = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(&TWENTYNINE,DDMMYYn8..));
**%PUT &P_DATE;
%LET P_YEAR = %SYSFUNC(YEAR(&P_DATE));
%LET P_MONTH = %SYSFUNC(MONTH(&P_DATE));**
```

The P_Date reveals the error:

> ERROR: Argument 1 to function MONTH referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not
>          a number.
>   ERROR: Invalid arguments detected in %SYSCALL, %SYSFUNC, or %QSYSFUNC argument list.  Execution
>          of %SYSCALL statement or %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC function reference is terminated.

But I cant get my head around it any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: &TWENTYNINE is not a number, it's a formatted date...

Comment: Thanks buddy, what would you do to change it so it reads correctly. Sorry Its been puzzling me for a few days. Ever had the moment you cant actually visualise the problem...

Comment: You need P_DATE to be 29 days from today?

Comment: Yep its all in the same file directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imbricating %sysfunc's is handy:

```
%LET P_YEAR = %SYSFUNC(YEAR(%SYSFUNC(TODAY())+29));
%LET P_MONTH = %SYSFUNC(MONTH(%SYSFUNC(TODAY())+29));
%PUT &P_YEAR &P_MONTH;
```

Results in:

```
2016 2
```

**EDIT**

(Try solving it by yourself first, but here's a full solution...)

```
data _null_;
  target = today() + 29;
  format target YYMMDDS10.;
  put target=;
  call symput("target", put(target, YYMMDDS10.));
run;
%put &target;

2016/02/24
```

Comment: Ill give this a whirl and get back to you, thank you so much for the speedy response.

Comment: Turns out I've messed up the P_Date as well. Its coming back as ********

Comment: See my edit. It's a bit of an overkill, but you have both the formatted variable and a macro variable holding the full date with slashes...

Comment: Thanks mate, wont check yours yet will try to save on my own, really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Hey any time, this is fun! :)

Comment: Hahaha nice! Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the source path to use for today's date then use the `TODAY()` function.  You can apply the `YYMMDDS` format to have it displayed as YYYY/MM/DD.

```
%let frompath=%sysfunc(today(),yymmdds10);
```

If you want to calculate the target path from the source path then you can use the `INPUTN()` function to convert it back to a date, add 29 and use `PUTN()` function to convert it back to a string.

```
%let topath=%sysfunc(putn(29+%sysfunc(inputn(&frompath,yymmdd10)),yymmdds10));
```